# Status Bar comes back after the user minimize the App (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm trying to hide the Status bar for the entire app so that it can truly work in full screen but the thing is when ever the user minimizes the app or press home button and then open the app the status bar reappears and does not go away,

Also when the app opens on first run there is some lag time in hiding the status bar (3 seconds) and then it goes away turning white

My app has only two Activities and I want the app to hide the status bar for both the activities

my main activity java

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setClickable(true);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.notherstore.in");
        WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        setContentView(webView);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading Store");
        pd.setMessage("This may take several Minutes...");
        pd.show();
    }

    public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

my splash screen activity java

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following flags,

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

and a full-screen theme in the manifest,

```
<activity
       android:name=".SplashScreen"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Edit:

If you are using AppCompatActivity then you need to set theme as below

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

If you want do dynamically then try to keep on OnResume()